# What is the equation for the nth number in a sequence if the next number is the sum of 1 minus that number's position with the previous number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms

I do not really know how to put it in clearer English, but basically, the first part of the series looks like this,
1,2,4,7,11,16,22,29,37,46,56,67,79,92,106...
Suppose I need to calculate the 768th member or the 999th member,
What would the equation be?
[the series looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYYYN.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote but your sequence appears to be the [Lazy Caterer's Seqeunce](http://oeis.org/A000124)   That is "the largest number of slices of pizza you can obtain with $n$ cuts".

Comment: The grammar used to describe this was certainly confusing, but it looks like your sequence is simply one more than the triangle numbers, $0,1,3,6,10,15,21,28,\dots$ given as $a_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have a recursion relation defining the sequence and you want to find a closed-form formula for an arbitrary term. Based on the title, it looks like you have $a_n = a_{n-1} + (n-1)$. Is that right?

Comment: i have edited the original post with a picture.

Comment: @lulu yes it does appear to be the lazy caterer's sequence judging by the numbers. I am reading that document now.

Comment: @Gary Moon yes exactly. but with that equations I cannot really find the 999th member.

Comment: I might be able to do it with the one @JMoravitz provided. I am weak at math haha.

Comment: To be clear, though, that sequence is indeed just one more than the triangular numbers as others have remarked.  Post edit, it looks like you got the sequence more along those lines than along the lines of the Lazy Caterer.

Comment: @CatVI Yes, I was just clarifying the sequence so I could answer.

Comment: @lulu yes, i am checking it out now and it does seem that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your sequence is defined by recursively as: $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1} = a_n + n$ for $n \geq 1$. In that case, you can just repeatedly substitute into the recursion relation to get the closed-form formula:
$$a_n = a_{n-1} + n-1 = a_{n-2}+(n-2)+(n-1) = a_{n-3} + (n-3) + (n-2) + (n-1)\ldots$$
This leads to
$$a_n = a_{n-(n-1)} + (n-(n-1)) + \ldots + (n-1)= a_1 + 1 + 2 + \ldots + (n-1) = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j.$$
Then, you can recall that $\sum_{j=1}^n j = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. This means that
$$a_n = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} j = 1 + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$

Comment: I have used the brute force method to get up to 40th I think, and it was tiring. I understand the math now and yes, it does seem to give the same results. Thank you very much for such a swift answer.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help.

Comment: The pleasure is all mind. And to double-check with what the other fine folks said, both the position and value are 1 more than the triangle number counterpart too. so if the value of the 4th triangle number is 10, then the (4+1)th or 5th member of the sequence will have a value of 11.

Comment: Indeed, that is correct. This can be seen from the formula: $a_{n+1} = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^n j$, which is just $1$ plus the $n$th triangle number.